# Finding the space a text takes on a matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to find the space a text on a matplotlib plot takes with respect to the coordinate system it's placed in?

For example, in the following plot, depending on what `max_val` is, the space "some text" takes will be different. If `max_val=1`, its length along x-axis is about 0.3 and height along y-axis is  about 0.05, but if `max_val=1000`, length=300 and height=50, etc.

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(8,4))
max_val = 100
ax.set_xlim(0,max_val)
ax.set_ylim(0,max_val)
x, y = (0.5*max_val, 0.5*max_val)
ax.annotate('some text', xy=(x,y));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_tightbox()` method on the Text object and invert transform this to your Data scale with:

```
# text is your text object
ax.transData.inverted().transform(text.get_tightbox(fig.canvas.get_renderer())
```

This will return coordinates for a bounding box in format of `[[bottom_left_x, bottom_left_y],[top_right_x, top_right_y]]`.

You can get the text object via `get_children` method on your ax object and selecting the right object by index, or by assigning `ax.annotate` method output to a variable.

In your code, you could do something like:

```
text = ax.annotate('some text', xy=(x,y))
[x1,y1],[x2,y2]=ax.transData.inverted().transform(text.get_tightbbox(f.canvas.get_renderer()))
```

If you then use this data to plot a bounding box with:

```
rect = plt.Rectangle([x1,y1],(x2-x1),(y2-y1), edgecolor = 'red', linewidth = 2 ,facecolor='white')
ax.add_patch(rect)
```

You will get this output with a bounding box drawn around the text:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Unrelated to my original question but just out of curiosity, is there a way to work out fontsize of `text` from `rect` or `x1,x2,y1,y2`?

Comment: @NewbieAF without some sort of custom implementation of mapping fontfamily/fontsize/case to visual size or vice versa I don't think that's possible. Changing fontfamily (let's say Calibri to Arial) changes the box bounds, lowercase/uppercase have different bounds too. That's just off the top of my head, different renderers might also have an effect.